# is there another site like freegeoip.net

Tags: location, ip, city

is this site not working any more as i cant get it to work, it used to work.

is there any RELIABLE service like it

http://freegeoip.net/

Comment: Author of freegeoip.net here. The site suffered a major DDoS attack on new year's eve and took almost a week to recover. Since then it's been running reliably.

Comment: Seems to be down a lot lately :(

Comment: freegeoip v3 can be downloaded and deployed on any linux server and requires no maintenance. It also ships as a Docker container so you can run it anywhere on the cloud. See https://github.com/fiorix/freegeoip/releases for details.

Comment: @fiorix, thanks for this service. Just a quick question, the public service limit of 10,000 queries per hour by default might or might not be a problem for me, so i just want to take the safe route early enough by downloading it and running my own instance.  However, i have zero experience on deploying such a server. Do u have or know of a walk-through that can get me started. Can i host on windows or my own instance must be hosted on a linux server?

Comment: I've also found freegeoip to be unreliable with an ajax request and hence using Tellize for now. May install freegeoip on my server and see how that goes instead. in fact i see their webpage is very slowly ip locating today.

Comment: hey @StackTrace a couple days ago I updated the instructions in the README file and that might help you.

Comment: @Volte yeah you got it, don't be mad

Comment: You can use: https://www.geoip-db.com/

Comment: After the deprecation, https://reallyfreegeoip.org was launched as an alternative with the same response format.

Answer (score 13):

You can also checkout: http://geoip.nekudo.com/

I just started this as an alternative to freegeoip. Is's completely free and open-source so you can also setup your own copy if you like.

Comment: Can you provide some instructions on how to set up a private instance of this?

Comment: @nekudo The beautiful thing about your API is that it is served over HTTPS. So glad I found it. Thank you!

Comment: After the deprecation of freegeoip.net, https://reallyfreegeoip.org was launched as an alternative with the same response format. No signup needed.

Answer (score 4):

To setup your own instance this is what you have to to:

1. Pull the sourcecode from the [github repsitory](https://github.com/nekudo/shiny_geoip) and put it on your server.
2. Run "composer install" to load all dependencies. (Install [composer](https://getcomposer.org) if you don't have it yet)
3. Download a copy of the [GeoLite2 database](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/) and put it into a "data" folder. The path do the database can be change in "www/index.php".
4. Point your webserver to the "www" folder and you're done.

There is an optional [PHP extension](http://maxmind.github.io/GeoIP2-php/) provided by Maxmind which you can install to increase database read performance.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you don't use the related component, you can find a list of services here: https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#street-address-services

I am not sure that all this services propose IP geocoding. At least [MaxMind](http://www.maxmind.com/en/web_services) allows that, but it is not free.