# Geocoding API not responding fast enough

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-geocoder

I am using the Geocoder gem but lately it does not seem to work.

I get this error:

```
Geocoding API not responding fast enough (use Geocoder.configure(:timeout => ...) to set limit).
```

My application_controller.rb is:

```
before_filter :lookup_ip_location

  private

    def lookup_ip_location
      if Rails.env.development?
        prr = Geocoder.search(request.remote_ip).first
        p "this is #{prr.inspect}"
      else
        request.location
      end
    end
```

This is development.rb:

```
# test geocoder gem locally
  class ActionDispatch::Request
    def remote_ip
      "71.212.123.5" # ipd home (Denver,CO or Renton,WA)
      # "208.87.35.103" # websiteuk.com -- Nassau, Bahamas
      # "50.78.167.161" # HOL Seattle, WA
    end
  end
```

I am loading an IP addresses from development.rb  to check if geocoder works locally, but it does not. I am getting the above error.

Also, when printing `prr` I get nil.

I also added a geocoder.rb initializer to raise the timeout to 15 seconds but even after 15 seconds of the browser loading the page I'm still getting the same message.

Is it broken? Should I use another gem? If so, do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interesting. I tried your exact methods, and was running into the same problems. I also tried bumping the timeout up to 60 seconds, and same error.

Then I noticed Geocoder uses `freegeoip`. So I went to see what that was all about. Lo and behold, `freegeoip.net` is down. Suspicious.

So I checked the [Geocoder documentation](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/blob/c466a0c3a21fcc776f8ed0392752059f83bee3c3/README.md) for any different ip address lookup services they offer. Sure enough, under "Ip Address Services", there are multiple offers. I tried the first one that does not require an API key, which was `:ipinfo_io`.

```
[18] pry(main)> Geocoder.configure(ip_lookup: :ipinfo_io)
=> {:timeout=>30,
 :lookup=>:google,
 :ip_lookup=>:ipinfo_io,
 :language=>:en,
 :http_headers=>{},
 :use_https=>false,
 :http_proxy=>nil,
 :https_proxy=>nil,
 :api_key=>nil,
 :cache=>nil,
 :cache_prefix=>"geocoder:",
 :basic_auth=>{},
 :logger=>:kernel,
 :kernel_logger_level=>2,
 :always_raise=>[],
 :units=>:mi,
 :distances=>:linear}
[19] pry(main)> Geocoder.search("144.138.175.101")
=> [#<Geocoder::Result::IpinfoIo:0x007fce5da5fe28 @cache_hit=nil, @data={"ip"=>"144.138.175.101", "city"=>"", "region"=>"", "country"=>"AU", "loc"=>"-27.0000,133.0000"}>]
```

And it works! But the response doesn't have much info. I would recommend looking at the other ip lookup services that Geocoder uses. Find one that is reliable and has enough response info for your needs. Seems that `freegeoip` is free, but can also be unreliable. Cheers.

EDIT: Found some related information about `freegeoip.net` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20882227/is-there-another-site-like-freegeoip-net). If you really wish to use `freegeoip`, looks like you can run your own instance. Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for checking it out. However i get this error `Please specify a valid lookup for Geocoder (:ipinfo_io is not one of: ` thats weird. unless i have to update my gem? EDIT: yes i had to update gem to use ipinfo. works great thank you very much!Seems though that i does not support https, does this mean i cannot use it on an https production app?

Comment: I believe your app can still use https, but the calls to `ipinfo.io` from your server will not use https. Depending on your use case, this may be acceptable for you. Optionally, `ipinfo.io` allows https with an api key and cost. I encourage you to also compare `ipinfo.io` with the other services!

Comment: i have just now setup google and provided api_key and when i try `request.location` and print it, it says i am in iraq, which i am not, i am located in Cyprus, on my production app, it says i am in philippines. Why is that?would not expect that from google...

Comment: I'm not sure why that would happen. Perhaps you can create a new SO question with more details.