# PlayFramework - How to use geolocation to redirect client to correct url based on country?

Tags: java, scala, playframework

In my play application I want to detect the country location of the client and change the url based on their country.

For instance, the client is based in Great Britain and they submit www.example.com I want the application to redirect them to www.example.com/gb

Will I need an external API to detect the country based on the IP address?
How will this be reflected in the routes file?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing currently in PlayFramework. In my opinion there are three solutions.

1. Redirect the user according to the locale from the request but that's not very accurate.
2. Use an [external API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20882227/is-there-another-site-like-freegeoip-net) as you said and force redirect the user.
3. Inform the user that the website is available in his locale/country. For example, Amazon or Ebay allow whatever TLD to the user.

The last solution seems the better for the user.

Comment: In order to implement the 3rd solution, you must gather and determine the country based on the IP address. How would this be implemented?

Comment: I meant passively inform the user like Ebay.com does with a dropdown of multiple flags. However if you want to actively redirect the user you must geo target him or you can ask him in a friendly way with a dialog box which TLD he prefers based on his locale.